# The filament is almost impossible to remove

Tags: marlin, pla, creality-ender-3, troubleshooting, heated-bed

Most people complain about the filament not sticking on build plate but mine is vice versa. At first it used to be very good. When I removed the magnetic bed the project would come off easily but for a few days it is like I glue it to the bed with epoxy. It is impossible to remove and when I remove the black projects from the bed I see white color at the bottom of the object printed. Maybe because of too much force but I don't know why this happens.

Comment: Increase the distance between the nozzle and the bed, for hints see [this answer](/a/13713).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had this problem on my second print.  The nozzle was too close to the bed. The only way I got it all off was to heat the bed. Then the PLA became a bit softer and came off pretty fast.

Answer (score 4):

This usually happens when your nozzle is too close to bed during the first layer.
  Quick fix is **redo bed levelling**.
  Clean your build surface.
Watch you first layer
[image]

Comment: You know the very first layer it does around the object. The thin layer. It seems very hard to remove. How can I remove that? It seems like pressed instead of printed

Comment: The very first layer it does around the object is called a skirt.
If your build surface if removable then remove it. Use something like a putty knife with a thin and sharp edge to remove the residue particle. Watch [this](https://youtu.be/ECcasNza1Oo)